# 'He inspires great loyalty in his staff' Is the person which is talked about (he) the superior of the staff or just a coworker?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

> **He inspires great loyalty in his staff**

My question is how do you think: is a person which is talked about the superior or the coworker in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"His staff" undoubtedly implies that 'he' is the employer or manager. Otherwise it would be *among his colleagues/coworkers*

Answer (score 0):

The use of "his staff" **suggests** that the person is inspiring loyalty in those who work **for** him, his subordinates, rather than his co-workers. That is definitely the most likely interpretation of the example sentence. But this sentence could be used when "*co-workers*" is intended. One cannot be sure without additional context.